# Porting codes from MATLAB to C(OpenCV)

Tags: c, matlab, opencv

I've been working on trying to port a small meanshift tracking program, which is sort of different from the meanshift that involves performing back-projection, from MATLAB to C, but I'm having some problems with it.

I don't know how to interpret some of the lines from MATLAB to C(OpenCV).

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2r9FmkcbNwAbHdtVEVkSW1SQW8

I put the 2 .m files, 1 .cpp file and a directory where pictures are placed for both programs to use on my googledrive.

"demo_MultiMeanShift_1st_ver_0413.m" is what I'd like to port to C,

"boxfilter.m" is the function that's found in the following website:
http://blog.csdn.net/wds555/article/details/23176313
(It's a Chinese website however)

and "Meanshift_demo.cpp" is what I've done so far.

There're mainly two parts that I don't know how to interpret from MATLAB to C:
1st part:

```
bas = zeros(hei,wid,N) ;
for i = 1 : 1 : N
    bas(:,:,i) = boxfilter( ones(hei,wid), floor(r/i) ) ;
end


Ic_mean = zeros(hei,wid,dep,N) ;


for i = 1 : 1 : N
    for d = 1 : 1 : dep
        %Average pixel value(s) of the object being tracked
        Ic_mean(pc(2)-(r+sw) : pc(2)+(r+sw), pc(1)-(r+sw) : pc(1)+(r+sw), d, i) = boxfilter(Ip(pc(2)-(r+sw) : pc(2)+(r+sw), pc(1)-(r+sw) : pc(1)+(r+sw),d), floor(r/i)) ./ bas(pc(2)-(r+sw) : pc(2)+(r+sw), pc(1)-(r+sw) : pc(1)+(r+sw),i);
        %Ic_mean(:,:,d,i) = boxfilter(Ip(:,:,d), floor(r/i)) ./ bas(:,:,i);        
    end
end

dis = zeros(1,N) ;
```

2nd part:

```
for i = -sw + pc(2) : 2 : sw + pc(2)
    for j = -sw + pc(1) : 2 : sw + pc(1)
        for d = 1 : 1 : N
            dis(d) = sqrt( ... % (p1(R1, G1, B1) - p2(R2, G2, B2))^2
                  ( Ic_mean(i,j,1,d) - Ip_mean(pc(2),pc(1),1,d) )^2 ...
                + ( Ic_mean(i,j,2,d) - Ip_mean(pc(2),pc(1),2,d) )^2 ...
                + ( Ic_mean(i,j,3,d) - Ip_mean(pc(2),pc(1),3,d) )^2 );
        end
        if  disMin > mean(dis)
            disMin = mean(dis) ;
            i_hold = i ;
            j_hold = j ;
        end
    end
end
```

In MATLAB I can read, access and change pixel values directly, such as:

Img(x,y) = 0 to set some pixel value to be 0
or
Img(:,:,1) = 1 to set the pixels of certain channel to all be 0.

Can I also do those things as rapidly as what's shown above is in OpenCV?

Answer (score 1):

> In MATLAB I can read, access and change pixel values directly, such
>   as:
>
> Img(x,y) = 0 to set some pixel value to be 0 or Img(:,:,1) = 1 to set
>   the pixels of certain channel to all be 0.
>
> Can I also do those things as rapidly as what's shown above is in
>   OpenCV?

Of course this is possible. To set value of single pixel use:

```
img.at<img_single_element_type>(y,x) = 0;
```

where `img_single_element_type` depends on mat type and might be double, unsigned char, int, etc... See documentation for more information.

To set values in whole image (or part of image) use [setTo](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=setto#mat-setto) method.

---

I don't know much about Matlab, so i can't help you with porting this code, but look at [this](https://github.com/zk00006/OpenTLD) and [this](https://github.com/gnebehay/OpenTLD) project. It's similar project (object tracker - Open TLD(Tracking Learning Detection) aka Predator) written in Matlab(first link) and ported to C++(second link). Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, currently I used the C-styled functions in OpenCV instead of the C++ ones. This may take me some time to get accustomed to it tho.

Comment: I still need to figure out how to access pixels in OpenCV. This has been making me trouble for some time.  Ty for your help.